# How do I diff 2 Perforce Client Specs

Tags: version-control, perforce, perforce-client-spec

I have two perforce clients (client-a, client-b) that each contain about 40 file specs. They are similar, but each client has several file specs that aren't included in the other.   I would like to find the differences between these client specs.  Ideally, the output would look something like this...

```
File specs in client-a and not in client-b:
//depot/dirA/...
//depot/dirG/...

File specs in client-b and not in client-a:
//depot/dirD/...
//depot/dirX/...
```

It would be nice if I could do something like `p4 diff -c client-a -c client-b` but after reading the documentation for [`p4 diff`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/diff.html) and [`p4 diff2`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/diff2.html), this doesn't seem possible.  I could resort to writing an awk script, but thought there might be a better solution.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [spec depot](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.092/manuals/p4sag/03_superuser.html#1083233).  After you've done that, you will be able to compare client specs (among other things) just like you compare source files.

[alt text http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/448/specdepot.png](http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/448/specdepot.png)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.  I prefer to use the command line tools, so I did 

`p4 diff2 //spec/client/client-a //spec/client/client-b`